# Apache SSI case insensitive matching

Tags: apache, ssi

I am trying to test the user agent to set a variable with apache SSI.

For example:

```
<!--#if expr="$HTTP_USER_AGENT = /chrome/" -->
    <!--#set var="isChrome" value="true" -->
<!--#else -->
    <!--#set var="isChrome" value="false" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

However, the match fails for 'Chrome'. Is there a way to specify the match should be case insensitive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:`<!--#if expr="$HTTP_USER_AGENT = /(C|c)hrome/" -->`